# How to get specific object from data

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
{
    type: 'Text',
    firstLanguage: {
      translation: 'When the Constituent Assembly passed the Objective Resolution?',
      option_a: '14th February 1949',
      option_b: '12th March 1949',
      option_c: '9th June 1949',
      option_d: '15th August 1949',
      correct_answer: 4
    },
    secondLanguage: {
      translation: 'متى أقرت الجمعية التأسيسية القرار الموضوعي؟',
      option_a: '14th February 1949',
      option_b: '12th March 1949',
      option_c: '9th June 1949',
      option_d: '15th August 1949',
      correct_answer: 4
    }
  },
```

This is the data I am getting in reposne
I want to get the firstLanguage objects in a single variable . These are comming multiple

Answer (score 1):

suppose you getting this data is response variable. you can do like this in node JS.

```
const response = {
    type: 'Text',
    firstLanguage: {
      translation: 'When the Constituent Assembly passed the Objective Resolution?',
      option_a: '14th February 1949',
      option_b: '12th March 1949',
      option_c: '9th June 1949',
      option_d: '15th August 1949',
      correct_answer: 4
    },
    secondLanguage: {
      translation: 'متى أقرت الجمعية التأسيسية القرار الموضوعي؟',
      option_a: '14th February 1949',
      option_b: '12th March 1949',
      option_c: '9th June 1949',
      option_d: '15th August 1949',
      correct_answer: 4
    }
};
const firstLanguage = response.firstLanguage;
console.log(firstLanguage,'firstLanguage');
```

Add Comment for any query Thanks.

Comment: We can simply use the destructure method, const { firstLanguage } = response

Comment: yes we can also used destructure method as describe by @BennisonJ